# concurrency issue encountered in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Two users on the same page from different machines and when they click submit together the both see each others page instead to seeing their own page.

How can I fix this concurrency problem in mvc3?

Thanks.

Comment: its your coding issue...not MVC...show us the code

Comment: are you using statics or caching?

Comment: @user2832064, When you cache something then all user will got same copy of cached instead of their own (version). Try to cache it with different key in case of different different user, show the code and people will help you to fix it.